# Dynamic JPQL query qith JOIN

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, jpql

Had to write a jpql query, based on the input need to add and condition and for some input had to need JOIN queries.

```
@Override
        public List<IncidentHdr> fetchIncidents(IncidentHdrDto incidentHdrDto) {

            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            query.append(ReposJPQL.GET_INCIDENT_DETAILS);

            Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            List<String> criteria = new ArrayList<String>();

            if(incidentHdrDto.getIncidentId() > 0) {
                criteria.add("inc.incidentId = :incidentId");
                parameters.put("incidentId", incidentHdrDto.getIncidentId());
            }

            if(incidentHdrDto.getCatCode() > 0) {
                criteria.add("inc.catCode = :catCode");
                parameters.put("catCode", incidentHdrDto.getCatCode());
            }

            if(incidentHdrDto.getType != null) {
                //here i need to generate a join query
                //SELECT * FROM INCIDENT JOIN CATEGORY_MAST ON(INCIDENT.CAT_CODE = CATEGORY_MAST.CAT_CODE) WHERE CATEGORY_MAST.TYPE_CODE = 16
            }



            Query q = em.createQuery(query.toString());
            logger.info("Get Incidents Query : "+query.toString());

            for (Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
                q.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }



            List<IncidentHdr> incidentHdrs = q.getResultList();
            return incidentHdrs;
        }
```

where as ReposJPQL is the base query which had a where condition.

```
public interface ReposJPQL {

    public String GET_INCIDENT_DETAILS = "SELECT inc FROM IncidentHdr inc WHERE 1 = 1" ;

}
```

Comment: Is there a requirement to always use `GET_INCIDENT_DETAILS ` base query and mold it to the query you need? A default filter can be used at entity level and you can use criteriaQuery for less error prone implementation.

Comment: default filter ? I didn't get that point.